# Computing the product of the ideals $\left(4,\frac{3+\sqrt{-71}}{2}\right)$ and $\left(3,\frac{1+\sqrt{-71}}{2}\right)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\frak{a}=\left(4,\frac{3+\sqrt{-71}}{2}\right)$ and $\frak{b}=\left(3,\frac{1+\sqrt{-71}}{2}\right)$ be the ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-71}]$. I would like to show that $\frak{a}\frak{b}=\left(12,\frac{-5+\sqrt{-71}}{2}\right)$. Clearly, $\frak{a}\frak{b}$ contains the ideal $\left(12,\frac{-5+\sqrt{-71}}{2}\right)$. How about the converse? In fact, I do not know how to write an arbitrary element in $\frak{a}\frak{b}$ explicitly since $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-71}]$ is not a PID. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tip:** The product of the two ideals is generated by the products of their generators.